# Adding Thousand Separator Automatically (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a code for my calculator

How could I do so that when the user would enter the numbers he would be separated by a space automatically?

I've been trying to find an answer for a long time, but nothing fits that it was **displayed right away**

---

[image: gif]

```
var currentInput: Double {
    get {
        return Double (displayResultLabel.text!)!
    }
    set {
        let value = "\(newValue)"
        let ValueArray = (value.components(separatedBy:"."))
        if ValueArray[1] == "0" {
            displayResultLabel.text = "\(ValueArray[0])"
        } else {
            displayResultLabel.text = "\(newValue)"
        }
        stillTyping = false
    }
}
@IBAction func numberPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let number = sender.currentTitle!

    if stillTyping {
        if (displayResultLabel.text?.characters.count)! < 14 {
            displayResultLabel.text = displayResultLabel.text! + number
        }
    } else {
        displayResultLabel.text = number
        stillTyping = true
    }
}
```

**Then what happened:**

```
@IBAction func numberPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let number = sender.currentTitle!

    if stillTyping {
        if (displayResultLabel.text?.characters.count)! < 14 {
            let formatter = NumberFormatter()
            formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
            let newNumber = NSNumber(value: Double(displayResultLabel.text! + number)!)

            displayResultLabel.text = formatter.string(from: newNumber)
        }
    } else {
        displayResultLabel.text = number
        stillTyping = true
    }
}
```

**Error**
[image]

```
var stillTyping = false
var dotIsPlaced = false
var firstOperand: Double = 0
var secondOperand: Double = 0
var operationSign: String = ""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to accumulate your value in a separate string that doesn't have the formatting applied rather than using the text field as your data model.  You can then format the decimal and display it in the label as required using a `NumberFormatter`:

```
let formatter: NumberFormatter = {
   let formatter = NumberFormatter()
   formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
   return formatter
}()

var currentInput: String = "0" {
    didSet {
        self.displayResultLabel?.text = self.currentDisplay
}

var currentValue: Double {
    return Double(self.currentInput) ?? 0
}

var currentDisplay: String {
    return formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value:self.currentValue)) ?? "0"
}

func addDigit(_ digit: Int) {
    if currentInput.count < 14 {
        let newValue = self.currentValue * 10 + Double(digit)
        self.currentInput = "\(newValue)"
    }
}

@IBAction func numberPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    guard let digit = Int(sender.currentTitle!) else {
        return
    }

    self.addDigit(digit)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what [`NumberFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter)s are for

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
if let newNumber = formatter.number(from: displayResultLabel.text! + number){
    displayResultLabel.text = formatter.string(from: newNumber)
}
```

Note that `NumberFormatter`s go both ways, and you can (and probably should) use them to parse numbers from strings, too

Comment: Error appears - Instance member 'numberStyle' can not be used on type 'NumberFormatter'

Comment: Sorry about that. I forgot the parens to actually instantiate it :P An similar example compiles on my machine now

Comment: After he started to enter 8888 (it changed to 888 8) and there was an error - "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional"

Comment: And Xcode has asked to change this line like this "displayResultLabel.text = formatter.string(from: newNumber as! NSNumber)"

Comment: I updated the code above one more time to include an `NSNumber` instantiation, as that's what `NumberFormatter`s accept

Comment: Xcode has asked to change this line like this  - "Value of optional type 'Double?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?"

Comment: Even though it is in the OP's code, you should remove the force unwrap. It is also better to accumulate the number into the double and format that to the label than to update the label and use that to produce the double

Comment: in line - let newNumber = NSNumber(value: Double(displayResultLabel.text! + number))  and the error still remains

Comment: You'll need to unwrap that `Double`, as it's being instantiated from a `String` (which the code above does now, too. This is what I get when my own tests doesn't match the question *perfectly* :P). @Paulw11 Could you post another answer with code illustrating what you mean?

Comment: I changed my code to just have the `NumberFormatter` handle the number parsing, too. You generally shouldn't do your own formatting (like adding spaces every 3rd number) before passing it into a function to convert a string to a number, but a `NumberFormatter` is more resilient to detecting things like that, instead of just crashing like `Double` does

Comment: @MichaelHulet After 4 entered numbers they are not entered simply remain 4 numbers and all (9 999)